# Unable to Configure Routes Properly in my ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am configuring my routes in asp.net mvc app where there are multiple routes and only first and last route works but the routes defined in the center of my route.config file are not working. Following is the code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Doctor",
        url: "admin/doctor/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "admin", action = "AddDoctor", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Admin",
        url: "admin/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "admin", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

}
```

Comment: I think you have to pass controller name into it like below:
`routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Admin",
        url: "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "admin", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );`

Comment: Thanks @SunilKumar. You were right. Problem Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot the `controller` part of your `Admin` route.

You should define it as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "admin", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```